# Vaadin Icons Svg Unicode value is a string literal

Tags: css, svg, vaadin, vaadin7

I am trying to use Vaadin Icons in our Vaadin application. I have the Vaadin-Icons.svg file. I want to use the angle-right icon but I find that the svg file has a string literal as unicode value. It looks like this

```
<glyph unicode="angle-right" d="M256 128h128l320 320-320 320h-128l320-320z" data-tags="angle-right" />
```

while i was expecting something like this

```
<glyph unicode="&#xe7b1;" d="M550.4 736l224-224h-774.4v-128h774.4l-224-224 89.6-89.6 384 377.6-384 377.6z" data-tags="arrow-right" />
```

How do I use it in the css file?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Vaadim, but the code looks like you're supposed to use the `data-tags` attribute for that purpose.

Comment: Are you writing the application in Java?

Answer (score 0):

The unicode value works as a ligature. Not sure, but maybe you are looking for the font icon instead, which you can more easily use from CSS? SVG’s are more useful when used within HTML.